# Duplicacion de datos al momento de guardar C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, base-de-datos

Tengo un pequeño inconveniente al momento de hacer el guardado en segundo plano se realiza el traspaso de información de una tabla quincenal a otra tabla histórica, al realizar el primer guardado funciona sin problema y cumple lo propuesto , pero si vuelvo a realizar un segundo guardado inmediatamente se duplica la información.

```
  private void administrativoToolStripMenuItem6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Trabajo"].ToString();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
        {
            conn.Open();
            string query = "select [id_empl],[cedu_empl],[dias_empl],[dias_vac_empl],[per_empl],[suelquin_empl],[otros_empl],[bon_empl],[transporte_empl],[fdr_val]" +
            ",[fdr_empl],[dec_val],[deciter_empl],[decicua_empl],[reintegro_empl],[cert_med_empl],[vacaci_empl],[iess_empl],[prestempr_empl]" +
            ",[consumoce_empl],[cadena_empl],[aire_spli_empl],[naviplan_empl],[comprastc_empl],[ventipp_empl],[presthipo_empl],[camaron_empl]" +
            ",[prestquiro_empl],[almuer_empl],[genes_empl],[multa_empl],[otrosd_empl],[extsal_empl],[imp_ren_empl],[empldome_empl],[suem_empl],[fecha_empl] from TBL_ROL_ADM";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
        if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Base de Datos TBL_ROL_ADMIN Vacia Llene los Datos Necesarios Para Continuar ", "SISROL", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
        else
        {
            cierreroles();
            MessageBox.Show("Proceso de Cierre Terminado Satisfactoriamente", "SISROL", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
```

Y este el método cierreroles que me realiza el guardado a la tabla histórica y posteriormente elimina la información en la tabla quincenal.

```
 public void cierreroles()
        {
            string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["trabajo"].ToString();
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
            {                
                string query = "INSERT INTO HIS_ROL_ADM ([id_empl],[cedu_empl],[dias_empl],[dias_vac_empl],[per_empl],[suelquin_empl],[otros_empl],[bon_empl],[transporte_empl],[fdr_val]"+
                ",[fdr_empl],[dec_val],[deciter_empl],[decicua_empl],[reintegro_empl],[cert_med_empl],[vacaci_empl],[iess_empl],[prestempr_empl]"+
                ",[consumoce_empl],[cadena_empl],[aire_spli_empl],[naviplan_empl],[comprastc_empl],[ventipp_empl],[presthipo_empl],[camaron_empl]"+
                ",[prestquiro_empl],[almuer_empl],[genes_empl],[multa_empl],[otrosd_empl],[extsal_empl],[imp_ren_empl],[empldome_empl],[suem_empl],[fecha_empl],[reg_empl])" + 
                " VALUES (@id_empl,@cedu_empl,@dias_empl,@dias_vac_empl,@per_empl,@suelquin_empl,@otros_empl,@bon_empl,@transporte_empl,@fdr_val"+
                ",@fdr_empl,@dec_val,@deciter_empl,@decicua_empl,@reintegro_empl,@cert_med_empl,@vacaci_empl,@iess_empl,@prestempr_empl,@consumoce_empl"+
                ",@cadena_empl,@aire_spli_empl,@naviplan_empl,@comprastc_empl,@ventipp_empl,@presthipo_empl,@camaron_empl,@prestquiro_empl,@almuer_empl"+
                ",@genes_empl,@multa_empl,@otrosd_empl,@extsal_empl,@imp_ren_empl,@empldome_empl,@suem_empl,@fecha_empl,@reg_empl)";
                string queryd = "DELETE FROM TBL_ROL_ADM ";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand(queryd, conn);
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_empl", Convert.ToInt32(row["id_empl"]));                    
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cedu_empl", Convert.ToString(row["cedu_empl"]));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dias_empl", Convert.ToDecimal(row["dias_empl"]));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dias_vac_empl", Convert.ToDecimal(row["dias_vac_empl"]));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@per_empl", Convert.ToString(row["per_empl"]));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@suelquin_empl", Convert.ToDecimal(row["suelquin_empl"]));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@otros_empl", Convert.ToDecimal(row["otros_empl"]));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bon_empl", Convert.ToDecimal(row["bon_empl"]));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@transporte_empl", Convert.ToDecimal(row["transporte_empl"]));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fdr_val", Convert.ToDecimal(row["fdr_val"]));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fdr_empl", Convert.ToDecimal(row["fdr_empl"]));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dec_val", Convert.ToDecimal(row["dec_val"]));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@deciter_empl", Convert.ToDecimal(row["deciter_empl"]));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@decicua_empl", Convert.ToDecimal(row["decicua_empl"]));                    
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reintegro_empl", Convert.ToDecimal(row["reintegro_empl"]));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cert_med_empl", Convert.ToDecimal(row["cert_med_empl"]));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vacaci_empl", Convert.ToDecimal(row["vacaci_empl"]));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iess_empl", Convert.ToDecimal(row["iess_empl"]));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prestempr_empl", Convert.ToDecimal(row["prestempr_empl"]));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@consumoce_empl", Convert.ToDecimal(row["consumoce_empl"]));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cadena_empl", Convert.ToDecimal(row["cadena_empl"]));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aire_spli_empl", Convert.ToDecimal(row["aire_spli_empl"]));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@naviplan_empl", Convert.ToDecimal(row["naviplan_empl"]));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comprastc_empl", Convert.ToDecimal(row["comprastc_empl"]));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ventipp_empl", Convert.ToDecimal(row["ventipp_empl"]));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@presthipo_empl", Convert.ToDecimal(row["presthipo_empl"]));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@camaron_empl", Convert.ToDecimal(row["camaron_empl"]));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prestquiro_empl", Convert.ToDecimal(row["prestquiro_empl"]));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@almuer_empl", Convert.ToDecimal(row["almuer_empl"]));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@genes_empl", Convert.ToDecimal(row["genes_empl"]));
                    if (row["multa_empl"] == null || Convert.ToString(row["multa_empl"]) == "" || row["multa_empl"].Equals("null"))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@multa_empl", 0);
                    }
                    else if (row["multa_empl"] != null)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@multa_empl", Convert.ToDecimal(row["multa_empl"]));
                    }
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@otrosd_empl", Convert.ToDecimal(row["otrosd_empl"]));
                    if (row["extsal_empl"] == null || Convert.ToString(row["extsal_empl"]) == "" || row["extsal_empl"].Equals("null"))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@extsal_empl", 0);
                    }
                    else if (row["extsal_empl"] != null)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@extsal_empl", Convert.ToDecimal(row["extsal_empl"]));
                    }
                    if (row["imp_ren_empl"] == null || Convert.ToString(row["imp_ren_empl"]) == "" || row["imp_ren_empl"].Equals("null"))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imp_ren_empl", 0);
                    }
                    else if (row["imp_ren_empl"] != null)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imp_ren_empl", Convert.ToDecimal(row["imp_ren_empl"]));
                    }
                    if (row["empldome_empl"] == null || Convert.ToString(row["empldome_empl"]) == "" || row["empldome_empl"].Equals("null"))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empldome_empl", 0);
                    }
                    else if (row["empldome_empl"] != null)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empldome_empl", Convert.ToDecimal(row["empldome_empl"]));
                    }
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@suem_empl", Convert.ToDecimal(row["suem_empl"]));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha_empl", Convert.ToDateTime(row["fecha_empl"]));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reg_empl", DateTime.Now);


                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conn.Close();

                    cmdd.Parameters.Clear();
                    conn.Open();
                    cmdd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Que podría estar ejecutándose mal que me causa el error.

De antemano les agradezco por su ayuda.

Saludos.

Comment: primero deberias mover tus queries como Stored Procedures y verificar  que funcionen correctamente del lado del servidor de datos. Despues los llamas desde codigo.

Comment: no se porque usar un dt para esto.. pero en algun momento lo vacias o controlas que tenga una sola fila?

Comment: Tienes que usar una Transaction si quieres ejecutar dos querys desde el mismo metodo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí publico la solución a mi pregunta con las recomendaciones que cada uno me dio.

```
 private void administrativoToolStripMenuItem6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        daoMetodos.Verificar_Roles_Admin();
    }
```

Como primera recomendación puse todo el código en otra clase para posteriormente realizar la llamada del método en la clase principal, el primer método me verifica que existan datos en la tabla quincenal para posteriormente continuar con el guardado a la tabla histórica como se ve en el código adjuntado.

```
 public void Verificar_Roles_Admin()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Trabajo"].ToString();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
        {
            conn.Open();                
           string query = "select [id_empl],[cedu_empl],[dias_empl],[dias_vac_empl],[per_empl],[suelquin_empl],[otros_empl],[bon_empl],[transporte_empl],[fdr_val]" +
            ",[fdr_empl],[dec_val],[deciter_empl],[decicua_empl],[reintegro_empl],[cert_med_empl],[vacaci_empl],[iess_empl],[prestempr_empl]" +
            ",[consumoce_empl],[cadena_empl],[aire_spli_empl],[naviplan_empl],[comprastc_empl],[ventipp_empl],[presthipo_empl],[camaron_empl]" +
            ",[prestquiro_empl],[almuer_empl],[genes_empl],[multa_empl],[otrosd_empl],[extsal_empl],[imp_ren_empl],[empldome_empl],[suem_empl],[fecha_empl] from TBL_ROL_ADM";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
        if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("La BD Quincenal esta Vacia", "SISROL", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            Cierre_Roles_Adm_Transaction();
        }
    }
```

Una vez que realice la verificación y existan datos se procede a llamar al método que realiza el cierre y pasa la información a la tabla histórica , en este método hago uso de Sql-Transaction , con 3 ejecuciones de query , el primero el procedimiento almacenado que realiza la inserción a la tabla histórica, el segundo que elimina la información de la tabla quincenal y el tercero que actualiza el campo de la hora en la que se realiza la ejecución.

```
 public void Cierre_Roles_Adm_Transaction()
    {
        string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Trabajo"].ToString();
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connstring))
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlTransaction transaction;
            //Inicia la Transaccion Local.
            transaction = connection.BeginTransaction("InicioTransacción");
            try
            {
                SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("GuardarTablaQuincenal", connection);
                SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM TBL_ROL_ADM ", connection);
                SqlCommand command3 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE HIS_ROL_ADM SET [REG_EMPL] = GETDATE() WHERE REG_EMPL IS NULL", connection);

                // Must assign both transaction object and connection 
                // to Command object for a pending local transaction
                command1.Connection = connection;
                command1.Transaction = transaction;
                command2.Connection = connection;
                command2.Transaction = transaction;
                command3.Connection = connection;
                command3.Transaction = transaction;

                command1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                command3.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                command1.ExecuteNonQuery();                    
                command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                command3.ExecuteNonQuery();

                // Attempt to commit the transaction.
                transaction.Commit();
                MessageBox.Show("Proceso de Cierre Terminado Satisfactoriamente", "SISROL", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);                   
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Excepción Tipo Commit " + ex.GetType() + " El Mensaje de Excepción: "+ex.Message, "SISROL", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);                    
                // Attempt to roll back the transaction. 
                try
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                }
                catch (Exception ex2)
                {
                    // This catch block will handle any errors that may have occurred 
                    // on the server that would cause the rollback to fail, such as 
                    // a closed connection.
                    MessageBox.Show("Excepción Tipo Rollback " + ex2.GetType() + " El Mensaje de Excepción: " + ex2.Message, "SISROL", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Gracias a los que respondieron y me ayudaron con sus recomendaciones.

Saludos.